# Recursion Understanding

Tags: recursion

In recursion how to identify calculations should be done on before recursion call or after recursion call?

e.g

```
// code for calculation and then recursion call
boolean xyz()
{
    x = xyz();

    if(x ==c ondition)
       return true;
}

// Code for recursion call then calculation 
boolean xyz()
{
    if(x == condition)
      return true;

  xyz();
}
```

In many tree problems I observed this scenario but not able to understand how it works and when to use what please provide suggestions

Comment: i want to ask many times we have precondition or postcondition check after recursive call to function so what is the difference in it.

Comment: That depends entirely on the algorithm? I don't understand how this can be answered in general. It's like asking what's the difference between having breakfast at home before you leave, and having breakfast once you get to your desk. Like, it depends on a million things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of the basic structure as "if we've reached the bottom return a base value, else go deeper."

```
void xyz()
{
   if(x==condition) 
   {
      return some_base_value;
   }
   else 
   {
      return xyz();
   }
}
```

Here's an example of a classic factorial function:

```
long factorial(int n)
{
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return(n * factorial(n-1));
}
```